# Additional script that refresh a certain page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to ask is there a way to load a script in any page? To be more specific, I would like to load a script which would refresh for example Google page on my computer every 5 seconds. I tried adding  thing in HTML and it works for the first time, but when it's refreshed my HTML is not there any more. I can understand this, because it gets information from server. But is there any way that I can upload my script or do something so I can refresh any page every 5 seconds as long as I want it?

Comment: When you refresh, the browser resets any changes you've made. The only way to do what you're talking about is by creating a browser plugin/extension

Comment: as @Howzieky said, you only can achieve it by some plugin/extension. if you use Firefox, you may find [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) useful.